# SQL - When I join an additional table, it adds rows to my results that I don't want to count

Tags: sql

I'm learning SQL, for the second time, and I'm not able to figure out how to join an additional table (that's required to access a field in that table that I want to sum), without it returning additional rows to the results, as that is giving me incorrect counts.

That is my problem, as I see it, but maybe my approach is wrong.

What I need to accomplish is to total the ItemPrice's that are found in the OrderItems table, per customer, for all their orders. I have done that, but not without getting the wrong counts for the number of orders, due to having to join that additional table.

Here is the abbreviated code for the problem I'm working on, followed by the results.  The results from running the code as-is on the left, and the results by un-commenting the 2 lines on the right.

```
select  customers.FirstName, Orders.CustomerID, count(*) as NumOfOrders

from Orders
    join Customers
        on orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID
--  join OrderItems
--      on OrderItems.OrderID=Orders.OrderID

group by customers.FirstName, Orders.CustomerID
having count(*) > 1
order by NumOfOrders desc


fname     ID    count                 fname      ID    count
---------------------                 ----------------------
David      4    3                     Allan       1    3
Heather    8    2                     David       4    3
Kris      18    2                     Frank       6    3
Bette     29    2                     Heather     8    2
Allan      1    2                     Simona     14    2
                                      Kris       18    2
                                      Yuki       27    2
                                      Bette      29    2
                                      Chanel     35    2
```

Comment: GIve the DB name/version/ sample data from order/customer and orderitem and your output. Would be plus if you use http://sqlfiddle.com for create and inset statements.

Comment: provide your sample table of Order, order item, customer...

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing since I don't have all info needed, but perhaps you can do 
`count(distinct Orders.OrderID)` to get the correct count?

```
select  customers.FirstName, Orders.CustomerID, count(distinct Orders.OrderID) as NumOfOrders
from Orders
    join Customers
        on orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID
    join OrderItems
        on OrderItems.OrderID=Orders.OrderID
group by customers.FirstName, Orders.CustomerID
having count(*) > 1
order by NumOfOrders desc
```

Maybe you need to adjust the `HAVING` clause to `having count(distinct Orders.OrderID) > 1` too?